# nginx stopped using server directive/proxy stopped working

Tags: nginx, proxy, docker-compose

Suddenly my nginx configuration stopped working.

```
events {}

http {
upstream node-app {
    server qa:3000;
}

server {
    listen      8080;
    server_name name.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://node-app;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  name.com;
    root         /var/www/name.com/webapp;
    auth_basic "Password required";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location ~ \.css {
        include             /etc/nginx/mime.types; # css files wont be loaded if mime type wont be text/css
    }
}
}
```

Nothing gets logged/works for connections to port 8080. I have tested if it is caused by the proxy by removing location block and instead using configuration from server at port 80 configuration, it is still not working.

I am using docker-compose to setup nginx and server listening at port 3000. Nothing has changed in the docker configuration since last time things were working.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: run `sudo nginx -t` to get what happend to nginx process

Comment: `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: I have posted another question after extensive investigation, which turned out the problem is not about nxing but request passing of ubuntu docker-compose. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522471/docker-proxy-not-passing-connections-to-ports-other-than-80-from-outside-localho